# Evaluate cells error in Mathematica

Tags: button

Clicking on the button generated by the following code:

```
Button["Start",
     SelectionMove[SelectedNotebook[], Before, Notebook];
     Catch[Do[SelectionMove[SelectedNotebook[], Next, Cell];
       Module[{r}, If[MatchQ[r = NotebookRead[SelectedNotebook[]],
          Cell["bishierherundnichtweiter", ___]], 
         NotebookDelete[SelectedNotebook[]];
         Throw[0], SelectionEvaluate[SelectedNotebook[]]]], {1}]]]
```

precedent cells are not evaluated and clicking it over again I get the following error:

[image]

Using Wolfram Mathematica 10.2. How can I fix it?

Comment: To the people who have voted to close this as unclear (3 so far): please comment and explain why you are voting to close if you choose to do that. To me it's pretty clear, I tried the OP's code and clicked the button repeatedly and in no time I got the same error message.

Comment: It does not produce the error message in version 9.0.1, and according to OP, not in 10.0 either. So it seems to be a bug in version 10.2. The question shouldn't be closed, in my opinion.

Comment: @Manu, no problem in 10.3 Win 10